# compile Dlib library with Yocto

Tags: yocto, dlib

I'm trying to cross-compile an application with yocto. The application uses Dlib library, so I have to make a recipe for Dlib. How should the recipe look like? @R.Gopi

When I try to build dlib recipe from  @astor555 , I get the following error:

```
ERROR: dlib-1.0+gitAUTOINC+3b794540ba-r0 do_package: QA Issue: dlib: Files/directories were installed but not shipped in any package:
  /usr/lib/cmake
  /usr/lib/cmake/dlib
  /usr/lib/cmake/dlib/dlib.cmake
  /usr/lib/cmake/dlib/dlib-release.cmake
  /usr/lib/cmake/dlib/dlibConfig.cmake
  /usr/lib/cmake/dlib/dlibConfigVersion.cmake
Please set FILES such that these items are packaged. Alternatively if they are unneeded, avoid installing them or delete them within do_install.
dlib: 6 installed and not shipped files. [installed-vs-shipped]
ERROR: dlib-1.0+gitAUTOINC+3b794540ba-r0 do_package: Fatal QA errors found, failing task.
ERROR: dlib-1.0+gitAUTOINC+3b794540ba-r0 do_package: Function failed: do_package
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With using [*devtool*](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#new-recipe-creating-the-base-recipe-using-devtool) I am was able to quickly generate **dlib.bb** recipe:

```
SUMMARY = "A toolkit for making real world machine learning and data analysis applications"
HOMEPAGE = "https://github.com/davisking/dlib"

LICENSE = "Boost-Software"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://dlib/LICENSE.txt;md5=2c7a3fa82e66676005cd4ee2608fd7d2 \
                    file://dlib/external/pybind11/LICENSE;md5=beb87117af69fd10fbf9fb14c22a2e62 \
                    file://dlib/external/libpng/LICENSE;md5=243135ddedf702158f9170807cbcfb66 \
                    file://docs/docs/license.xml;md5=2e6ff4080dcb217d4d300b90e9aabb5b \
                    file://examples/LICENSE_FOR_EXAMPLE_PROGRAMS.txt;md5=57eee82829ed297e23d84de5f905afee \
                    file://examples/video_frames/license.txt;md5=127ee508b60a6be9dea8af3b441993dc \
                    file://python_examples/LICENSE_FOR_EXAMPLE_PROGRAMS.txt;md5=064f53ab40ea2b6a4bba1324149e4fde"

SRC_URI = "git://github.com/davisking/dlib.git;protocol=https"

PV = "1.0+git${SRCPV}"
SRCREV = "3b794540baeabbcd033b544230401967106d5483"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

inherit cmake
```

Comment: this recipe just gets the dlib library from git? beacause I don't see where it installs the library

Comment: Have You able to build this recipe ? In recipe workspace -
 *tmp/work/<target arch>/dlib/<dlib version>/image* should be all of the outputs prepared for next stages.

Comment: And what will be shipped to the dlib package?
At least add
FILES_${PN} += "/${base_prefix}"

Comment: @ɛIc_ↄIз I think it is not needed, default configuration comes from (bitbake.conf)[https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/conf/bitbake.conf#n290] adjust outputs from *dlib.bb* recipe correctly. Please take look (try build recipe) and let know if everything is build and shipped correctly.

Comment: @astor555 I am not able to build the recipe. I get the following error: // I edited my post, check it please

Comment: I did not face *installed-vs-shipped* QA issues, please tell which Yocto release are You using. I was testing this on *sumo* 2.5 version.

Comment: I'm using Yocto Project 2.2 morty

Comment: @ɛIc_ↄIз what is/contain `${base_prefix}`? When I add this line, it build the recipe without errors.            `FILES_${PN} += "/${base_prefix}"`

Comment: @DanVison when you build for target (which is your case), it is empty. This command adds everything from the image folder to the package you build. The error you got without this line means "compilation has resulted in the following file ..., but I wasn't instructed to either include them to some package, or to delete them".

Comment: But I don't recommend you to leave this command. It is better to create do_install_append function, and remove the listed files and directories. If you don't know how to do it, please create another question.

Comment: @ɛIc_ↄIзThank you for your explanation. I have one more question. This recipe is for dlib - a library. But I can't find any `*dlib*.so` file in `tmp/` .Why?  When I installed opencv library, I found a lot of `.so` files in `tmp/usr/lib/`

Comment: @DanVison you should find your library by the following path: build/tmp/work/arch.../dlib/version.../package/...