# dlib library with yocto

Tags: yocto, dlib

I'm trying to compile dlib library with yocto. I have the following recipe:

```
SUMMARY = "A toolkit for making real world machine learning and data analysis applications"
HOMEPAGE = "https://github.com/davisking/dlib"

LICENSE = "Boost-Software"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://dlib/LICENSE.txt;md5=2c7a3fa82e66676005cd4ee2608fd7d2 \
                    file://dlib/external/pybind11/LICENSE;md5=beb87117af69fd10fbf9fb14c22a2e62 \
                    file://dlib/external/libpng/LICENSE;md5=243135ddedf702158f9170807cbcfb66 \
                    file://docs/docs/license.xml;md5=2e6ff4080dcb217d4d300b90e9aabb5b \
                    file://examples/LICENSE_FOR_EXAMPLE_PROGRAMS.txt;md5=57eee82829ed297e23d84de5f905afee \
                    file://examples/video_frames/license.txt;md5=127ee508b60a6be9dea8af3b441993dc \
                    file://python_examples/LICENSE_FOR_EXAMPLE_PROGRAMS.txt;md5=064f53ab40ea2b6a4bba1324149e4fde"

SRC_URI = "git://github.com/davisking/dlib.git;protocol=https"

PV = "1.0+git${SRCPV}"
SRCREV = "3b794540baeabbcd033b544230401967106d5483"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

FILES_${PN} += "/${base_prefix}"

inherit cmake
```

I found out that it's better to create do_install_append function, and remove the listed files and directories. What should I write in do_install_append function ?
last topic: [compile Dlib library with Yocto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51102780/compile-dlib-library-with-yocto)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please ask a full question, I had to dig into previous questions to find out what you're asking.

`$libdir/cmake/*.cmake` files should be packaged into `PN-dev`.  Current oe-core master does this automatically but releases don't yet.  Just add to your recipe:

```
FILES_${PN}-dev += "${libdir}/cmake"
```

Comment: After I added `FILES_${PN}-dev += "${libdir}/cmake"` I get some errors when I try to build:  `do_rootfs: dlib not found in the feeds in build/tmp/deploy/rpm` `do_rootfs: This is often caused by an empty package declared in a recipe's PACKAGES variable`

Comment: That's a totally unrelated point.  By default the Debian-style renamer is active so a package that contains just a library gets renamed to be the library name, so the actual package is most likely called libdlib or similar.  If you're explicitly depending on the package instead of letting library dependecies happen magically, then you'll need to use that.

Answer (score -1):

Dlib has created intermediate artifacts, that should be removed, as you don't need them, and bitbake doesn't allow you to leave any files without attention.

```
do_install_append() {
    rm -rf ${D}/${libdir}/cmake
}
```